# Kivy Switch Callback

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am very new to Kivy. Please help me make the switch widget work correctly.
Here is my current code:

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''

    StackLayout:
        orientation: 'lr-tb'
        padding: 10
        spacing: 5

        Button:
            text: 'S1'
            size_hint: .2,.1

        Button:
            text: 'S2'
            size_hint: .2,.1

        Button:
            text: 'S3'
            size_hint: .2,.1

        Switch:
            id: switch_id
            on_active: root.switch_on(self, self.active)
            size_hint: .2, .1



    '''))
```

I know I need to add the follow code, but I'm not sure how to implement with classes. Here is the addition I mentioned:

```
    def switch_on(self, instance, value):
        if value is True:
            print("Switch On")
        else:
            print("Switch Off")
```

Any help on how to correctly put this all together would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder



theRoot = Builder.load_string('''

StackLayout:
    orientation: 'lr-tb'
    padding: 10
    spacing: 5

    Button:
        text: 'S1'
        size_hint: .2,.1

    Button:
        text: 'S2'
        size_hint: .2,.1

    Button:
        text: 'S3'
        size_hint: .2,.1

    Switch:
        id: switch_id
        on_active: app.switch_on(self, self.active)
        size_hint: .2, .1

''')

class theApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return theRoot

    def switch_on(self, instance, value):
        if value is True:
            print("Switch On")
        else:
            print("Switch Off")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    theApp().run()
```

Note that in the `kv` string, instead of `root` (which would be the `StackLayout`), I am using `app`, which refers to the `theApp` class.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: Hey i just found this today and your work did really hel me to find my mistake